# How do I pass a function with a fixed parameter to another method in C?

Tags: c

Suppose I have a print Function which takes a void* as an argument:

```
Print(void *instance)
```

How can I Set the member of a struct to this method?

```
struct Foo
{
    void(*Print)(); //this does not match to Print above!
    //void(*Print)(void* Instance); //This would but I cannot change this
}
```

So how would I have to change this method:

```
void Init()
{
    struct Foo* k = malloc(sizeof(Foo));

    Foo->Print = &Print(k);   //does not work?!
    //Foo->Pring = &Print;     //would work if types were the same
}
```

I want to set a function pointer inside a struct with a Fixed argument.

Basically this is a way to implement object oriented code in ANSI-C.
The source project is this: [Object Orientation in C?!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1117825/Object-Orientation-in-C)

This would be about changing this piece of C Code:

```
String* r = New_String("Hello");
r->Free(r); //this works
r->Free();  //this is how it should be!
```

So that the instance does not have to be passed to the methods themselfes.

**Summarized**: Goal is to get the Foo instance inside Print called like Foo->Print();

Comment: How do you plan to call it?  Are you trying to use a pointer to a function that takes a parameter, then have it called with the parameter effectively filled in for you to whatever you specified when you assigned the function pointer?  That isn't possible... you'd need to take a different approach.  Each call would have to pass the parameter explicitly.

Comment: That would be exactly the problem. Other languages support it like this:
Foo.Print = ()=>Print(k); Maybe somehow one can add k to the stack for every call manually?

Comment: It appears you have posted pseudo C++ code and want to do the same in C.  The trouble is that the code simply appears like invalid C code. Suggest incorporate your comment into the post and try to clarify your goal more, perhaps will adding sample calls.

Comment: Note: C does not have "methods", it has functions.  The essential difference between these appears to be near the root of your problem.  You can employ some elements of object-oriented programming in C, but it looks very different than in C++.  You would be best off, I think, asking about what you are trying to accomplish (in sufficient specificity), rather than about this particular, non-viable approach to accomplishing it.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. I want to achieve C++ like syntax. The best so far is Foo->Print(Foo). I want to get Foo inside of Print without passing it as an argument explicitly. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With:

```
Foo->Print = &Print(k);
```

you are assigning a function pointer *and* you are "calling" the function with a parameter. That is wrong. What you can do is:

```
Foo->Print = Print;
Foo->Print = (void(*)())Print;    // if compiler complains, use a cast
```

Because `Print` is a function, the compiler will use its address when assigning it to the function pointer field of the struct. But because your `Print` function is incompatible with the `Print` field, you must use a cast to silence the compiler.  Your `Print` function is casted to a "function that can take any number of parameters". The casting is safe here as long as you call it with at least one parameter. Only do this casting when you know what you are doing, or undefined behavior will follow.

Once the function pointer is assigned, you can now call it with your parameter:

```
Foo->Print(k);
```

Comment: Bad thing is k should not be used afterwards. I have clarified my question for this.
Crazy things are also allowed. Goal is to get the Foo reference inside Print somehow. Stack manipulation, Assembler, anything goes!

Comment: Howabout adding a member `k`, such as `Foo->k= k;` and so `Foo->Print(Foo->k);`?

Comment: This is the way it works now. Even better: Foo->Print(Foo) since you only need the address. But I need Foo->Print();

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question/comment, but you can call `Foo->Print(Foo)` and you _have_ `Foo->Print();` only you shouldn't call it without at least one parameter because your `Print(void *instance)` expects a parameter.